# Replicating YearFrac() in R for historical dates

Tags: r, excel, function

I'm a new user of stackoverflow and R. Sadly, I've come across an error in my code that I can't seem to solve for which I'm trying to seek out some help. In case I've put this question somewhere unappropriately, I excuse myself in advance.

The general idea was to write a function resembling the "YearFrac" function of Excel in R. The reason for this is that I need to discuss the age, including decimals, of inidivdual bonds for a particular assignment at university. Rather than doing it in Excel on the raw data file itself, I'd like to do it in R (and gain more experience in R whilst doing so). Furthermore, the reason as to why I can't rely on the RQuantLib package its "yearFraction" function is that I've got dates that predate 1901.

The VBA source code regarding the implementation of YearFrac() has served as my example, which you can find [here](https://lists.oasis-open.org/archives/office-formula/200806/msg00039.html).

My code is the following:

```
IsLeapyear=function(year){
# A year is a leap year if:
# It is evenly divisible by 4
# Not if it is evenly divisible by 100
# But it is if it is evenly divisible by 400
return(
       ((year %% 4 == 0) & (year %% 100 != 0)) | (year %% 400 == 0)
       ) # The %% operator functions like "Mod" in Excel's VBA
}

IsEndOfMonth=function(Day, Month, Year){
# Indicate the number of days that are in a month
# Making the difference between not only 30 & 31
# But also for February in particular when we are dealing with a leap year
if(Month == 1 | Month  == 3 | Month == 5 | Month == 7 | Month == 8 | Month == 10 | Month == 12) # January, March, May, July, August, October, December
  {
    Day == 31
  }
else
  {
    if(Month == 4 | Month == 6 | Month == 9 | Month == 11) # April, June, September, November
      {
        Day == 30
      }
    else
      {
        if(Month == 2) # February case
          {
            if(IsLeapyear(Year) == T)
              {
                Day == 29
              }
            else
              {
                Day == 28
              }
          }
      }
  }
}

# Example
IsEndOfMonth(19,8,1861)

Days360=function(StartYear, EndYear, StartMonth, EndMonth, StartDay, EndDay){
return(
        ((EndYear-StartYear)*360) + ((EndMonth-StartMonth)*30) + (EndDay-StartDay)
      )
}

TmpDays360Nasd=function(StartDate, EndDate, Method, UseEom){
# We set the startdate and enddate inputs as actual dates
require(lubridate)
t0 <- dmy(StartDate)
t1 <- dmy(EndDate)

# Pull the days, months and years apart from the startdate and enddate
StartDay <- day(t0)
StartMonth <- month(t0)
StartYear <- year(t0)
EndDay <- day(t1)
EndMonth <- month(t1)
EndYear <- year(t1)

if(EndMonth == 2 & IsEndOfMonth(EndDay, EndMonth, EndYear) & 
   ((StartMonth == 2 & IsEndOfMonth(StartDay, StartMonth, StartYear) == T) | Method == 3))
  {
    EndDay == 30
  }
if(EndDay == 31 & (StartDay >= 30 | Method == 3))
  {
    EndDay == 30
  }
if(StartDay == 31)
  {
    StartDay == 30
  }
if(UseEom == T & StartMonth == 2 & IsEndOfMonth(StartDay, StartMonth, StartYear) == T)
  {
    StartDay = 30
  }
return(Days360(StartYear, EndYear, StartMonth, EndMonth, StartDay, EndDay))
}

# Random dates chosen to test code snippits
x <- "19-08-1861"
y <- "01-02-1868"

# Example
TmpDays360Nasd(StartDate = x, EndDate = y,Method = 1,UseEom = T)

TmpDays360Euro=function(StartDate, EndDate){
# We set the startdate and enddate inputs as actual dates
require(lubridate)
t0 <- dmy(StartDate)
t1 <- dmy(EndDate)

# Pull the days, months and years apart from the startdate and enddate
StartDay <- day(t0)
StartMonth <- month(t0)
StartYear <- year(t0)
EndDay <- day(t1)
EndMonth <- month(t1)
EndYear <- year(t1)

if(StartDay == 31)
  {
    StartDay == 30
  }
if(EndDay == 31)
  {
    EndDay = 30
  }
return(Days360(StartYear, EndYear, StartMonth, EndMonth, StartDay, EndDay))
}

# Example
TmpDays360Euro(StartDate = x, EndDate = y)

TmpDiffDates=function(StartDate, EndDate, Basis){
  if(Basis == 0) # atpmBasis30360
    {
      DiffDate <- TmpDays360Nasd(StartDate, EndDate, Method = 0, UseEom = T)
    }
  if(Basis == 1 | Basis == 2 | Basis == 3) # atpmBasisActual atpmBasisActual360 atpmBasisActual365 by use of actual count of days
    {
      DiffDate <- as.numeric(dmy(EndDate)-dmy(StartDate)) # The difference between date objects is always in days, which is why we don't need to specify this
    }
  if(Basis == 4)
    {
      DiffDate <- TmpDays360Euro(StartDate, EndDate)
    }
  return(DiffDate)
  }

# Example
TmpDiffDates(StartDate = x, EndDate = y, Basis = 4)

TmpCalcAnnualBasis=function(StartDate, EndDate, Basis){
# We set the startdate and enddate inputs as actual dates
require(lubridate)
t0 <- dmy(StartDate)
t1 <- dmy(EndDate)

# Pull the days, months and years apart from the startdate and enddate
StartDay <- day(t0)
StartMonth <- month(t0)
StartYear <- year(t0)
EndDay <- day(t1)
EndMonth <- month(t1)
EndYear <- year(t1)

if(Basis == 0 | Basis == 2 | Basis == 4) # atpmBasis30360 atpmBasisActual360 atpmBasisE30360
  {
    AnnualBasis <- 360
  }
if(Basis == 3) # atpmBasisActual365
  {
    AnnualBasis <- 365
  }
if(Basis == 1) # atpmBasisActual
  {
    if(StartYear == EndYear)
      {
        if(IsLeapyear(StartYear) == T)
          {
            AnnualBasis <- 366
          }
        else
          {
            AnnualBasis <- 365
          }
      }
    else if((EndYear-1 == StartYear) & ((StartMonth > EndMonth) | ((StartMonth == EndMonth) & StartDay >= EndDay)))
      {
        if(IsLeapyear(StartYear) == T)
          {
            if(StartMonth < 2 | (StartMonth == 2 & StartDay <= 29))
              {
                AnnualBasis <- 366
              }
            else
              {
                AnnualBasis <- 365
              }
          }
        else if(IsLeapyear(EndYear) == T)
          {
            if(EndMonth > 2 | (EndMonth == 2 & EndDay == 29))
              {
                AnnualBasis <- 366
              }
            else
              {
                AnnualBasis <- 365
              }
          }
        else
          {
            AnnualBasis <- 365
          }
      }
    else
      {
        for(z in StartYear:EndYear)
          {
            if(IsLeapyear(z) == T)
              {
                AnnualBasis <- AnnualBasis + 366
              }
            else
              {
                AnnualBasis <- AnnualBasis + 365
              }
          }
        next
          {
            AnnualBasis <- AnnualBasis / (EndYear - StartYear + 1)
          }
      }
  }
return(AnnualBasis)
}

TmpYearFrac=function(StartDate, EndDate, Basis){
nNumerator = TmpDiffDates(StartDate, EndDate, Basis)
nDenom = TmpCalcAnnualBasis(StartDate, EndDate, Basis)

TmpYearFrac = nNumerator/nDenom

return(TmpYearFrac)
}

# Example
nNumerator = TmpDiffDates(StartDate = x, EndDate = y, Basis = 1)
nDenom = TmpCalcAnnualBasis(StartDate = x, EndDate = y, Basis = 1)
TmpYearFrac(StartDate = x, EndDate = y, Basis = 1)
```

If I run the code I continiously get an error regarding the "Basis=1" case for my second to last step (i.e. the "TmpCalcAnnualBasis" function) where the "AnnualBasis" seems to be undefined for some reason I can't seem to grasp.

Regarding the actual solution, the difference between the two dates given by "x" and "y" in my code should come to 6.453114305 years on an Actual/Actual basis.

Thank you very much in advance!

For both my question, as well as the method of posting, I'm looking forward to your comments.

Comment: Hi, in `lubridate` there is a `leap_year` function and you may use other functions to calculate your fractions...
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html

Comment: The lubridate package also has `decimal_date`.

Comment: Appears you are missing an {else} option in the logic for Basis = 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answers thus far. I do suspect the error is located in the last part of the "TmpCalcAnnualBasis" function where we loop through each of the consecutive years between the start- and end year. I assume R doesn't know to store and utilize the previous annual basis (of the first year in the actual lifespan between start and end years) and go through the loop for each of the sonsecutive years. Is there some way I can store the "AnnualBasis" that's connected to each z in the sequence from start- to end year?